# Difficulty with listing function

Tags: python

Write a function named "counting" that takes a list of numbers as a parameter and returns the number of values in the input that are between 29.88 and 48.05 not including these end points. (My code below)

```
def counting(number):
    sum = 0
    for x in number:
        if (29.88 < x < 48.05):
            sum = sum + x
        return sum
```

How do I return the number of values in the input instead of the first number of an input?

Comment: Your `return` is inside the loop, which will make it return inside one iteration. Outdent it one level so it is outside the for loop. Also, you are not asked for the _sum_ of the numbers, but their _count_. When you _sum_, you add the element itself to the cumulative total. What do you add when you _count_?

Comment: Append the numbers to a list and return the length of the list.

Answer (score 1):

your return statement is indented too deep; you should return it after the for loop. also [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum) is not a good name as it is a built-in function that you overwrite.

and you should add `1` to the sum (you are counting) and not `x` itself.

you could also try this using the built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sum#sum):

```
def counting(number):
    return sum(29.88 < x < 48.05 for x in number)
```

(this is actually short for `sum(1 for x in number if 29.88 < x < 48.05)` and works because `True` is basically `1` and `False` is basically `0`).

Comment: Sorry, misread what you did. Correct on all counts (though sum of boolean might be a bit hard for a newbie)

Comment: @vash_the_stampede `number` is a list, and therefore should be iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Or to be similar to yours:

```
def counting(number):
    c = 0
    for x in number:
        if 29.88 < x < 48.05:
            c += 1
    return c
```

Or can do one-liner, `len`:

```
def counting(number):
    return len([29.88 < x < 48.05 for x in number])
```

Comment: @vash_the_stampede `number` is a list, and therefore should be iterable.

Comment: @ElyFialkoff that is corrected , reviewed OP post I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) on your list to keep only elements that the given function evaluates to true.

```
def counting(number):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: 29.88 < x < 48.05, number)))
```